# How can I delete certain text from multiple post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have imported over 150+ blogs from an old wordpress site onto my new wordpress side. In my old site, I used a shortcode in all the blogs that showed the five most recent blogs. However, I am using a widget to get this functionality now.

**The problem is:**

The shortcode text is still in all of my blog.

**My question:**

Is there anyway to get rid of the shortcode text in every post from my blog category. More specifically, can I remove the string '[5mostrecentblogpost]' in the post in my blog category?

Answer (score 0):

Run this sql code:

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `text` = REPLACE(text, '[5mostrecentblogpost]', '');
```

where **posts** - is posts table name and **text** is content field;